# How to pass image in POST request?

Tags: c#, .net

I learn API for one site, I need to pass image like post request.
This is my code:

```
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\test\myImage.jpg");
    var str = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    Post(uri, GetParams("file", str));

    private static string Post(string uri, NameValueCollection parameters)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var response = client.UploadValues(uri, parameters);

                return Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
            }
        }
   private static NameValueCollection GetParams(params string[] param)
        {
            var result = new NameValueCollection();
            if (param.Length % 2 != 0)
                return result;
            for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i += 2)
                result[param[i]] = param[i + 1];
            return result;
        }
```

I never used API for pass some file, maybe a do it wrong? My methods working with simle parameters, maybe I must to pass image something else?

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Doesn't it work? Why not? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I get (500) internal server error.

Comment: And what is the internal error?

Comment: Error is't write in View Detail. https://yadi.sk/i/A6TYispmyWdEt

Comment: Check the response from the server. There might be a pointer in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var response = client.UploadFile(apiUrl, @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\asd.jpg");
            }
```

It is working